# AJAX script failing to put parameter

Tags: ajax

I have created a php script that I know works. I try communication to it with the following ajax call:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://larsbak.dk/schedule/GET/schedule.php");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
}
request.send("id=201303560&interval=100000");
```

When i use the above script the server respons with error with error 104, which means that id parameter is not set. Why is this happening?

Comment: You're missing a `}`. Is that a typo or is that your error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are making a GET request, so you can't have a request body. Change that to `"POST"` or move the data to the query string.
2. You are claiming you are sending `"application/json"`, which `"id=201303560&interval=100000"` is not. You are sending `"application/www-x-form-urlencoded"` data.
3. You forgot to end (`}`) your `onreadystatechange` handler

Comment: Thanks you !
I didn't knew the first thing you mentioned.